# Build html with word table merged cells python

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I would like to build the table loaded from word in html, but a big problem is the merged cells, the best result I got was returning the value of the cells without repeating the merged cells, but I stopped there, not knowing how I can proceed

```
from docx import Document

def iter_unique_cells(row):
    prior_tc = None
    for cell in row.cells:
        this_tc = cell._tc
        prior_tc = this_tc
        yield cell


document = Document("document.docx")
for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in iter_unique_cells(row):
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                print(paragraph.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite the `iter_unique_cells` function to also return whether the current cell is merged or not. You can then integrate this information into the html by adding `colspan="2"` to the `<td></td>` elements. That should merge the cells (horizontally). To build the html, I would declare a string outside all of the loops and add each element's opening tag at the start of each iteration and the closing tag at the end.

```py
from docx import Document

def iter_unique_cells(row):
    ...  # modify to return cell, is_merged

document = Document("document.docx")
html = ""
for table in document.tables:
    html += "<table>"
    for row in table.rows:
        html += "<tr>"
        for cell, is_merged in iter_unique_cells(row):
            html += "<td colspan='2'>" if is_merged else "<td>"
            for paragraph in cell.paragraphs:
                html += f"<p>{paragraph.text}</p>"
            html += "</td>"
        html += "</tr>"
    html += "</table>"
```